# Internal SATA vs. PCIe-NVMe: Any compatibility?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, pci-express, nvme

I'm looking at the Lenovo T470p laptop that allows either a SATA storage drive or a PCIe-NVMe drive.

Thing is, I already have a SATA SSD I'd want to use internally for now, but I want to be able to upgrade to PCIe-NVMe in the future if possible -- all internal (not external).

Is there any possible way to make this work? Are either of them compatible with the other, perhaps through an adapter that'd fit? Searching online doesn't really yield anything on this, so I'm not sure.